# Can we also define $R^iF(i=0,1,\cdots)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology

[image]

Let $F:\mathcal C\to \mathcal D$ be an additive covariant functor between Abelian categories. Assume $\mathcal C$ has enough injective objects. We can also define $R^iF(i=0,1,\cdots)$, can't we?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can. There are two reasons people usually assume left exact though. The first is that it is convenient to have $R^0 F(A)=F(A)$, which uses the left exactness of $F$.

The other reason is that you can also define the left derived functor of $F$, and you would like it to be zero above degree zero so that the right derived functors capture all the cohomological data. This is a weaker reason than the first, but still nice to have.

That being said, left and right derived functors of arbitrary functors can be very useful.

Comment: Can you provide an example to your last claim? I have never encountered derived functors of inexact functors.

Comment: @Wojowu sure. The one example I know where it is nice is that it turns the bounded derived category into a functor, and the bounded below derived category into a functor as well. Then we get that compositions turn into spectral sequences via the Grothendieck spectral sequence

Comment: Thanks, though I'm afraid my understanding of both spectral sequences and derived categories is way too superficial for that to make any sense :P